# Change colour list

Tags: ionic2

I have a problem because I can't change the colour my ion-list.
My .html is like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Contactos
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="telefonos" padding>
<ion-list class="MyList" >
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
        <div align="center">
            {{item.title}}
        </div>  
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and my .scss in like this:

```
.MyList{
    background-color: #58B43F;
    color : #ffffff !important;
    box-shadow : 0px 6px 10px #888888;
}
```

box-shadow work fine, but my list is still white and the letters black.

Somebody know what is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Your `.scss` was added in `app.core.scss`?

Comment: Thanks for reply me Juliano, yes, my .scss is added in my app.core.scss. All is correct in my code?

Comment: try using .MyList .item{ //Your css for background and color}

Comment: YES!!! Thanks you very much Aish, work fine :)